# Forward to a new JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I need to forward to another JSP page based on so-called "action" parameters.

I have the following piece of code from servlet

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String action=request.getParameter("action");

    if(action=="login"){ 
        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp");
        requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
    };
}
```

I have a JSP page "login.jsp". When I type the following url

```
http://localhost:8080/AgileScrumBoard/MainController?action=login
```

the browser doesn't forward me to the login.jsp page. What might be an issue?

Comment: Your problem is due to basic Java. Check the duplicate Q/A.

Comment: Use `equals()` to compare equality of objects..

Comment: there should be a picture of Homer Simpson ...